# Sharepoint 2010 GetListView Linq XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Trying to process the XML returned by the web service List.asmx from sharepoint, and I can't seem to get to the pull the fields from the Default View.

I have tried variations on the following

```
    var viewFields = (from x in xData.Descendants(ns + "ListAndView")
                     where x.Element("View").Attribute("DefaultView").ToString() == "TRUE"
                     select x.Elements("ViewField")).ToList();
```

Sample XML

```
    <ListAndView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <List DocTemplateUrl="">
        <Fields>
          <Field ID="{03e45e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634}" DisplayName="test" Name="test"/>
        </Fields>
        <RegionalSettings>
          <Language>1033</Language>
          <Locale>1033</Locale>
          <AdvanceHijri>0</AdvanceHijri>
          <CalendarType>1</CalendarType>
          <Time24>False</Time24>
          <TimeZone>480</TimeZone>
          <SortOrder>2070</SortOrder>
          <Presence>False</Presence>
        </RegionalSettings>
        <ServerSettings>
          <ServerVersion>0</ServerVersion>
          <RecycleBinEnabled>True</RecycleBinEnabled>
          <ServerRelativeUrl>/test</ServerRelativeUrl>
        </ServerSettings>
      </List>
      <View Name="{2EDDCDF0-B93D-41A9-83B9-89E347ED93F9}" DefaultView="TRUE" >
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="FALSE" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="field1" />
          <FieldRef Name="field2" />
          <FieldRef Name="field3" />
        </ViewFields>
      </View>
    </ListAndView>
```

the linq statement should make sure that it only returns the FieldRef from the view that is define as the default one, more than one view can be returned.

After some Guidance by Selman22 I was able to accomplish this by doing the following

```
var view = xData.Descendants(ns + "View").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("DefaultView") == "TRUE");
var f = (from x in view.Descendants(ns + "FieldRef")
        select (string) x.Attribute("Name")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `ToString` will return you *type name* of the `Attribute`, not the `Value`.Therefore this statement will always return **false** and you get nothing.

```
x.Element("View").Attribute("DefaultView").ToString() == "TRUE"
```

Instead you should use explicit cast to get attribute's value:

```
(string)x.Element("View").Attribute("DefaultView") == "TRUE"
```

And you are trying to `Select` more than one Element with `x.Elements("ViewField")` so you should use `SelectMany` instead to get a `List<XElement>` :

```
xData.Descendants(ns + "ListAndView")
     .Where(x => (string)x.Element("View").Attribute("DefaultView") == "TRUE")
     .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("ViewField"))
     .ToList();
```

This should give you all `ViewField` elements.If you want only `Values` of the `Name` attributes that belongs the `FieldRef` elements use this:

```
xData.Descendants(ns + "ListAndView")
     .Where(x => (string)x.Element("View").Attribute("DefaultView") == "TRUE")
     .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("ViewField"))
     .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("FieldRef").Select(y => (string)y.Attribute("Name")))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: I also tried the following  var viewFields = (from x in xData.Descendants(ns + "ViewFields")
                                  where (string)x.Parent.Attribute("DefaultView") == "TRUE"
                                  select (string)x.Attribute("Name")).ToList();

Comment: So far not able to get to the field1, field2, field3.

Comment: @Vince you are not using the query that I wrote.After Where you should use selectmany.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try without linq?

This is how I would do.

Assuming you have the following object:

```
var listItems = client.GetListItems(listGuid, null, null, viewFields,
                                            null, null, null);
```

I would get the viewfields iterating though the collection using a simple for loop:

```
var listOfViewFields = new List<string>();

foreach (XmlNode node in listItems)
{
   if (node.Name == "rs:data")
   {
      for (int f = 0; f < node.ChildNodes.Count; f++)
      {
      if (node.ChildNodes[f].Name == "z:row")
      {
        var xmlAttributeCollection = node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes;
        if (xmlAttributeCollection != null)
        {
            listOfViewFields.Add(xmlAttributeCollection["ows_FIELD YOU WISH TO RETRIEVE"].Value);
        }
     }
  }
}
```